# Banner Ads not showing up Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, admob

I'm trying to get a Banner ad appear in my main screen but it won't show up. I used the firebase_admob 0.11.0+1 package. I created the firebase and google admob accounts, got them both linked together and got the appId and the banner ID and added the code but it doesn't work.

I also added the appID in the manifest file as given in the package

```
const String testDevice = 'YOUR_DEVICE_ID';
const testAppId = "ca-app-pub-6340236221743124~6413606161";
const testAdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-6340236221743124~6413606161";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      title: "Start of the app",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: testDevice != null ? <String>[testDevice] : null,
    keywords: <String>['foo', 'bar'],
    contentUrl: 'http://example.com',
    childDirected: true,
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
  );

  BannerAd _bannerAd;

  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    _bannerAd = createBannerAd()..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('AdMob Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[

                RaisedButton(
                    child: const Text('SHOW BANNER WITH OFFSET'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _bannerAd ??= createBannerAd();
                      _bannerAd
                        ..load()
                        ..show(horizontalCenterOffset: -50, anchorOffset: 100);
                    }),]),),),),);}}
```

Edit: Error log

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\laksh\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\5324cf3d856f90a58788658b9d99824d\play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_admob...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the issue above.
```

app/src/build.gradle below

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.new_test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add some error logs

Comment: @griffins sorry my bad. I added the error logs

Answer (score 0):

Well, as i see it, you dont have a problem in your code. The build error shows something wrong with your build.gradle abd AndroidX.

Can you reply me with your build.gradle or add it to your original post?

B.T.W. - please take a look at this github issue -
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2511

iDo.

Comment: I checked the github one, tried adding the dependency in it but still doesn't work. I added the build.gradle file to the post